# What is wrong with this Oracle query? ( ORA-00904: “md.valores”,"COD_TIPO_EXPE": invalid identifier)

Tags: oracle

I am trying to write an SQL query. If it works in Oracle SQL Developer, I will use it in TableAdapters query. This is the query;

```
        SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT   cexp.expediente.num_expe "Num. Expediente",
                 cexp.expediente.nif nif, cexp.expediente.interesado nombre,
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'NUMERO_FACTURA', cexp.md_valores.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Numero Factura",
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'IMPORTE_FACTURA', cexp.md_valores.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Importe bruto",
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'IMPORTE_NETO', cexp.md_valores.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Importe neto",
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'FECHA_PRESENTACION_FACTURA', cexp.md_valores.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Fecha recepcion"
            FROM cexp.md_propiedades a

                 RIGHT JOIN
                 (cexp.expediente RIGHT JOIN cexp.md_valores
                 ON cexp.expediente.num_expe = cexp.md_valores.num_expe)
                 ON (a.propiedad = md_valores.propiedad)
               AND (a.cod_tipo_expe = md_valores.cod_tipo_expe) 
           WHERE cexp.expediente.cod_tipo_acto = '12EO' 
        GROUP BY cexp.expediente.num_expe,
                 cexp.expediente.interesado,
                 cexp.expediente.nif,
                 cexp.expediente.cod_tipo_expe)
```

[image: THIS IS THE FAIL]
Text: ORA-00904: "md_valores"."COD_TIPO_EXPE": identificador no válido

Comment: Is `cexp` your schema name?

Comment: May be should be cexp.md_valores.cod_tipo_expe and cexp.md_valores.propiedad

Comment: Please post the error as text, not image

Comment: The error message suggests you've got `"md_valores"` as a quoted identifier somewhere, but it isn't in the code you've shown. Is there more - maybe an order-by clause? The query in the error dialog also doesn't match what you've posted, so it could be in your real select list, or really anywhere in your real query...

Comment: @AlexPoole
This is the same query, only the query is executed in VS and this change * for "Num.Expediente", nif, nombre, "Numero Factura" ...

Comment: The error says that the column `COD_TIPO_EXPE` does not exist on the table `md_valores`

Comment: From the end of error you also have `"a".` instead of `a.`. Are you changing the quoting, or is that happening automatically? If it runs in SQL Developer then table `md_valores` exists and has column `cod_tipo_expe`, the problem is that in the data dictionary it's `'MD_VALORES'` not `'md_valores'`, which is what the quoted identifier expects. If VS is adding the quoting then change all your unquoted identifiers to uppercase to see if that helps. I think it's a setting, sure I've seen this before somewhere...

Comment: @BobJarvis Yes, but i try CEXP.md_valores.Cod_tipo_expe (and this exist) and the same error ...

Comment: @AlexPoole This is a query delivered for my boss
Edit: And in my query i dont use a, this generate automatically

Comment: Does cexp.expediente.cod_tipo_expe exist?

Comment: I think we need to see the code that is passing this query to the driver; along with the driver version and any changes you've made to its settings. If it is adding the double-quotes for you then you either need to figure out how to stop it doing that, or change the query so it won't break - e.g. by making all the unquoted identifiers uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Your `FROM` clause seems to be unorganized. I'm not really sure how are you trying to `RIGHT JOIN` those tables. Best I could organize it is:

```
FROM cexp.md_propiedades a
   RIGHT JOIN cexp.md_valores
           ON ( a.propiedad = md_valores.propiedad
                AND a.cod_tipo_expe = md_valores.cod_tipo_expe) 
   RIGHT JOIN cexp.expediente 
           ON cexp.expediente.num_expe = cexp.md_valores.num_expe
```

See if it work this way.

The error you show indicates that the column `COD_TIPO_EXPE` doesn't exists either on the table you called it `md_valores.cod_tipo_expe` or on the table that you use the alias `a.cod_tipo_expe`. Please check whether one of this options is true and fix it.

**EDIT**

Since you are using the schema name (`cexp`) on all your tables it may be because you miss it on the `md_valores` table.

```
FROM cexp.md_propiedades a
   RIGHT JOIN cexp.md_valores
           ON ( a.propiedad = cexp.md_valores.propiedad              --here
                AND a.cod_tipo_expe = cexp.md_valores.cod_tipo_expe) --here
   RIGHT JOIN cexp.expediente 
           ON cexp.expediente.num_expe = cexp.md_valores.num_expe
```

Comment: The same error. I think cexp.md_valores.propiedad but this fail too

Comment: @FranciscoJavierYanesDelgado Try the Edit I just did. If it don't work you will have to show us the `md_valores` structure also the `md_propiedades` structure so we can check.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand how are you joining the tables. If it doesn't give you error, see if you are getting your expected output. If not then you might have to swap `right join` with `left join` at one place.

Also I am assuming that all the columns used in query exists in the given tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT   c.num_expe "Num. Expediente",
                 c.nif nif, c.interesado nombre,
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'NUMERO_FACTURA', b.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Numero Factura",
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'IMPORTE_FACTURA', b.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Importe bruto",
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'IMPORTE_NETO', b.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Importe neto",
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'FECHA_PRESENTACION_FACTURA', b.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Fecha recepcion"
    FROM cexp.md_propiedades a
        RIGHT JOIN
    cexp.md_valores b
        ON (a.propiedad = b.propiedad AND a.cod_tipo_expe = b.cod_tipo_expe)
    RIGHT JOIN      
        cexp.expediente c 
        ON c.num_expe = b.num_expe
    WHERE c.cod_tipo_acto = '12EO' 
    GROUP BY c.num_expe,
    c.interesado,
    c.nif,
    c.cod_tipo_expe
    )
```